# Deploying Single Page app from appveyor to azure

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, kudu, appveyor

I'm trying to figure out how to continuously deploy a single page application from appveyor to an azure website. I'm in a bit of a bind because I don't have access to the azure directly, so I'm trying to figure out as many details before contacting the admin, but the appveyor/azure documentation is leaving me with some questions.

My Goals:

1. Deploy a static site after it's built or trigger azure to do a deployment after a successful build. The app is written in typescript with angular and a bunch of other dependencies that get compiled and bundled into a static site.
2. I **do not** want the end user to ever know a deployment is taking place, so any incremental copying to a live environment is out.
3. I **do not** want to check in derived files or builds into the repo.

I currently have a build system that bundles the static site it in a zip archive. So my questions are:

1. Will using the WebDeploy provider meet my goals? Will there be any downtime during deployments if I deploy the zip archive as an artifact?
2. Is there another approach that would work better?
3. Is there a way to do this with azure automated deployments? For example, trigger azure to deploy after a successful build. If so, can kudu handle cloning a private submodule as part of the deployment process. I saw that they have submodule support, but I couldn't figure out from the docs if there would be any authentication issues with private submodules.

FYI, the build system is 100% NodeJS driven and independent of the windows ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

AppVeyor will will automatically deploy to an Azure website.  Use the website below to setup your deployment.

http://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question about what web deploy is and if it meets the goals I specified.

Comment: Web deploy generates the artifact as a zip file and pushes it to Azure.

I am still kind of unsure on your users noticing the change but I have not had issues.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll give it a shot. I was able to convince the admin to give me a test site to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Users are going to notice the change if the static files are not cached in their browsers or if they do a hard reload. Regardless of the implementation method, It is advisable to use a CDN (content delivery network). Connect the CDN endpoints to your app service and have the DNS point to the CDN instead of app service. The CDN will serve the static files to the end user instead of the app service itself. The CDN caches the last deployed files and continues serving them to end user until you purge them. Hence, you can keep deploying to your app service and the end user doesn't get affected by your deployments at all since they are accessing your site via CDN instead of app service. Once you have a stable deployment, you can purge your CDN and the latest code will be cached to the CDN again from your app service.

To answer your question about deploying the code, Regardless of the CI/CD system you use, FTP deployment from azure CLI can be one of the methods. [Click here for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-deploy-ftp). However, WebDeploy is the most standard methods of all when you deploy to an app service.